# Assigning key-equivalent to NSToolbarItem?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstoolbar

How can I set a key equivalent for a NSToolbarItem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't—toolbar items don't have keyboard shortcuts. You need a menu item that does the same thing with the right shortcut.

All toolbar items should have a corresponding menu item anyway [according to Apple](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/XHIGWindows/XHIGWindows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000961-BABIFCFJ):

> A toolbar is useful for giving users
>   immediate access to the most
>   frequently used features in an
>   application. *Any item in a toolbar
>   should also be available as a menu
>   command.*